# mailchimp ecomm/order-add using campaig_id error message "There is no record with unique id "" in the database"

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm trying to send an order with the `id_campaign` (ecomm/order-add), but by putting it throws me an error message , someone knows to be

```
$postData = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'id' => $order,
    'campaign_id'=>'xxxxx',
    'shipping'=>$price,
    'tax'=> $tax,
    'order_date' => date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('G:i:s').'-700',
    'items' => $itemsMail,
    'store_id'=>"xxxxxx", 
    'total'=>$subtotal,
);
```

```
There is no record with unique id "" in the database
```

if I delete the `id` of the campaign function works correctly , so I assume that is the id that I cause the error.

Comment: It looks like you're sending an empty `id` parameter?

Comment: if I do a var_dump , if the variable contains a value or I think  
array(9) { ["email"]=> string(17) "asd@asd.com" ["id"]=> string(6) "179834" ["campaign_id"]=> string(10) "e35b9ed329" ["shipping"]=> string(5) "35.00" ....... } Error:There is no record with unique id "" in the database

Comment: this is my array,                                         array(9) { ["email"]=> string(17) "asd@asd.com" ["id"]=> string(6) "179834" ["campaign_id"]=> string(10) "e35b9ed329"....}